# ProGuard rules and line number in crash report

Tags: android, libgdx, proguard

I my using LibGdx based android game, I have used the below Gradle, `proguard-rules.pro`. In the crash report, I do not see source file and its line number. Anything I am missing ?

**Gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**'proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

**Crash Report - Android Developer console**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at com.a.b.g.a (g.java:110)
at com.b.b.a (b.java:11)
at com.a.b.d.g (d.java:492)
at com.a.b.d.a (d.java:485)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.k.a (k.java:356)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.j.onDrawFrame (j.java:457)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun (GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run (GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

[image: Crash Report 2]

[image: Crash Report 3]

Comment: Did you misspelling the proguard file name?

Comment: yes .. it is corrected now in the question.

Comment: This is `NullPointerException` not `ClassNotFoundException`.  Do you have more information about the error stack trace? Did it reference to a line in your source code?

Comment: This is the only info on the crash report in Google play developer console.. added some more unknown crashes like this in the edited question

Comment: upload your mapping.txt to your project firebase console to deobscure your crash reporting..

Comment: Mapping file is already uploaded

Comment: This crash report can be obtained when you test signed apk on your phone or emulator. Before your upload apk and mapping to developer console

Comment: yes those are done perfectly. In some cases I am getting the details with filename and line number. but in some cases I am not getting.. that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need setup your proguard rules according [official article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ProGuard-DexGuard-and-libGDX). In my case rules not required:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
```

Make sure that file *proguard-project.txt* stored in *android module*, not in project root.

Comment: what about these 2 statements that you have mentioned. Do I need to add to get the source details ?

Comment: You can get _deobfuscated_ stack trace only for exceptions occurred after attaching your mapping file

Comment: yes even now still it is the same case. I guess the crash is inside LibGdx module. Not sure how to list those as well